# Sleep thread before hiding control in WinForms?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms

In a WinForms environment, I want to wait a specified amount of time before hiding a user control, but I don't want to freeze the entire UI. I can't kick off to another thread because I have to service the UI components on the thread they were created on. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use a [System.Windows.Forms.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.timer.aspx).  The `Tick` event will execute on the UI (message loop) thread.

Answer (score 1):

Starting a second thread for this works fine as long as you use `Invoke` to communicate with the form from your thread.

However, the best way would be to use a `Timer`.